# How to prevent crash when interstitial dismissed while main UI is changing?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uicollectionview, interstitial

I have an Swift application that shows Interstitial ads when I open this. At the same time, I load a call to show the response list of objects from server into a UICollectionView.

Sometimes if the items into UICollectionView is loaded at the same time that interstitial is closed my app crash. It's happen because the main thread is called from the interstitial and UICollectionView load...

How can I prevent this? Some ideas?

I tried add the interstitial into a background thread, but obviously isn't works.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
}
```

The library to load insterstitial is Smart Ad Server:

And my code is:

```
let sasAdPlacement: SASAdPlacement = SASAdPlacement(siteId: myId, pageId: myId, formatId: myId)
sasInterstitial = SASInterstitialManager(placement: sasAdPlacement, delegate: self)
sasInterstitial.load()
```

Comment: Need more code about how you're showing the interstitial ad at the first place and also how/when you're dismissing it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added code, and interstitial is dimissed from owner button and the library not allow control for this... @atulkhatri

Comment: Just wondering if you had a look at this documentation: https://github.com/smartadserver/smart-display-ios-samples/blob/master/ObjCSample/ObjCSample/SampleControllers/Interstitial/InterstitialViewController.m .It tells you how to show the interstitial from a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Put your UI in background thread certainly make your app crashed. I don't know why your UICollectionView load and setup your interstitial ads can make conflict and crashed. But if that's true. Try setup your ads after a period of time. Something like this :

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2) { [ weak self] in
            // TODO: Setup your ads here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation, if needed:
http://documentation.smartadserver.com/displaySDK/ios/integration/interstitial.html

I guess you will find your solution in using the delegate in combination with a DispatchQueue:

```
DispatchQueue(label: "interstitial", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: DispatchQueue.main).async {
    sasInterstitial.load()
}
```

So, please try:

```
class InterstitialViewController: UIViewController, SASInterstitialManagerDelegate {

   func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       showInterstitial(withPageID: 1234, formatID: "XYZ", debug: true)        
    }

    // MARK: - SASInterstitial

    func showInterstitial(withPageID pageID: Int, formatID: String, debug: Bool = false) {

        let adPlacement = SASAdPlacement(siteId: "xxxxxxxx", pageId: pageID, formatId: formatID)
        let placement = debug ? SASAdPlacement(testAd: .inAppBiddingInterstitial) : adPlacement
        let interstitialManager = SASInterstitialManager(placement: placement, delegate: self)

        DispatchQueue(label: "interstitial", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: DispatchQueue.main).async {
            interstitialManager.load()
        }

    }

    // MARK: - SASInterstitial delegate

    func interstitialManager(_ manager: SASInterstitialManager, didLoad ad: SASAd) {
        print("Interstitial has been loaded")
        manager.show()
    }

    func interstitialManager(_ manager: SASInterstitialManager, didAppearFrom controller: UIViewController) {
        print("Interstitial is presenting")
    }

    func interstitialManager(_ manager: SASInterstitialManager, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
        print("Interstitial has failed to load with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func interstitialManager(_ manager: SASInterstitialManager, didFailToShowWithError error: Error) {
        print("Interstitial has failed to show with error: \(error.localizedDescription))")
    }
}
```